# Get a value from an input in JavaScript and use it in Java

Tags: javascript, java

I work on an application and I want to connect the front end (JavaScript) with the back end (Java). I have an input in HTML. When a user inputs something, by clicking on a button, I want to get that value in Java, so I can perform some actions on it. How can I do this? Thank you!

```
<input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Input...">
<button type="button" id="button" onclick="loadResults()">Search</button>
```

Comment: You have to serialize the content you want to send (usually JSON, but it could also be something else) and then send it to the backend by using `XMLHttpRequest` or any wrapper that your framework provides

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way I can see is getting the value from the input using the id property, like so:

```js
const inputValue = document.getElementById("input").value
```

and then it is expected that you have some kind of API setup on your java backend, if so you can use the `fetch` built in function to make a `HTTP request` to you java backend
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API